# Is there a better way to write this in jQuery?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$(".sectionHeader").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).parent();
    while (row.next().length != 0) {
        row = row.next();
        if (row.children().first().is('th')) return;
        row.toggle();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have rows in the table that are section headers, in that case, you can collapse until the next sectionHeader like this:

```
$(".sectionHeader").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil(".sectionHeader").toggle();
});
```

You could make it more efficient with `delegate()` like this:

```
$("#sectionTable").delegate(".sectionHeader", "click", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil(".sectionHeader").toggle();
});
```

This attaches one event handler for the entire table instead of 1 per `.sectionHeader` row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".sectionHeader").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().each(function(index, element){
      if($(element).children().first().is('th')) return;
      $(element).toogle();
    });
});
```